# mod_wsgi file cannot import global_settings

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I tried getting mod_wsgi to work, but my server returns a 500 internal error.

I have tried various configurations for apache_mydjango.conf and django.wsgi.

Gist with code: https://gist.github.com/mdaniels5757/f6b486cda45206623087

Thanks for any help!

Comment: ``"C:/envs/trying_unifi/trying_unifi/apache/django.wsgi"`` should not be string, right?

Comment: Fixed that, but it still has the same error.

Comment: can you do ``print "test"`` in your django.wsgi and see if it is really being seen?

Comment: Yes, it can be seen in the log.

Comment: the path to settings seems to be wrong in your django.wsgi

Comment: Thanks, that error is fixed!